# page 1 is not paged

Tags: php, pagination, homepage, conditional-tags

I have rules that only work on paginated pages (is_paged). However, they don't work on page number one (/page/1). This one is behaving exactly like the homepage (!is_paged), but unlike pages 2,3,4 etc. I want to prevent page 1 from behaving like the homepage and have it behave just like any other page.

```
if (strpos($url,'/page/1') || is_paged()) {include 'paged.php'; } // this is to load a different template for paged results
if (is_home() && !is_paged() && !$paged = 1) echo 'good'; else echo 'bad'; // this is what i want to do inside the page and cannot. It returns 'good' on both homepage and page 1
if (is_home() && !is_paged() && !strpos($url,'/page/1')) echo 'good'; else echo 'bad'; // this returns 'bad' on both
if (is_home() && !is_paged()) echo 'good'; else echo 'bad'; //this returns 'bad' on both
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at this example that allows you to drill down to page number 1 of pagination? http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#Testing_for_paginated_Pages

Comment: It would be helpful to see your code.

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT - SOLVED: OK, so for whoever else looks for this, I found a workaround that is actually quite straightforward: on the paged.php template, set a variable such as $paged = true, than instead of !(is_paged()) use !($paged).

Answer (score 1):

do you mean you want a conditional for page 1 of all home queries which have more than one page as result?

try to use `$wp_query->max_num_pages`;

example:

```
if (is_home() && $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 && !is_paged()) echo '/page/1'; else echo '/';
```

Comment: I'm not sure, I think not, because I tried the code and it doesn't do what I want.
I have two different pages: one is index.php, heavily customized, cms style.
the other is "page/1", which shows the latest posts in order, blog style.
While I manage to load the correct template with the strpos thing,
wordpress still doesn't seem to know where it is. It says both are is_home and !is_page.
OTOH, conditionals that identify $paged = 1 also trigger on the homepage and do things I don't need there.

What I want is to have them separated: what triggers on home doesn't trigger on page 1 and viceversa.

Comment: with the new explanation, I doubt as well that my suggestion will work. possibly consider using a page template instead of the 'heavily customized' index.php; and use index.php for the latest posts.

Comment: That would be fine, but is there a way to load the page template with the base url and yet not redirect when on index/page 1?